# Python Selenium - how to click and pick from the dropdown list items without select tag

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to Python and Selenium, try to automate filling out the form and get the game gift.

Here is a html, and it uses list items instead of select tag.

```
<tr>
                <th>Server Name</th>
                <td>
                    <!-- toDev liのdata-value属性に設定して頂いた値が下のhiddenに入ります。 --> <input
                    type="hidden" name="server" class="js-selected-server">
                    <ul class="serialForm__select js-select-form" data-type="server">
                        <li><span class="js-selected-text">Select Server</span>
                            <div class="serialForm__select--btn">
                                <img class="iconArrow" data-type="primary"
                                    src="/img/nav/nav_arrow01.svg"> <img class="iconArrow"
                                    data-type="secondary" src="/img/nav/nav_arrow02.svg">
                            </div></li>
                        <li data-value="1">Orchard(KOR)</li>
                        <li data-value="2">Dynasty(CHN)</li>
                        <li data-value="3">Warlord(SEA)</li>
                        <li data-value="4">Conquest(US)</li>
                        <li data-value="5">Invincible(JP)</li>
                        <li data-value="6">Inferno(TW)</li>
                        <li data-value="7">Ascension(KOR)</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
```

Script is able to click the dropdown menu, but not able to pick any of the listed items.
[image]

I tried the following and none of those works.

```
# dropdown = Select(select_server)
# dropdown.select_by_visible_text('Conquest(US)')
# dropdown.select_by_index('4')
```

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

import time

edge_options = {
    "executable_path": "/edgedriver_mac64/msedgedriver",
    # ofcourse change path to driver you downloaded.
    "capabilities": {
        "platformName": 'mac os x',  # I get this from Chrome driver's capabilities
        # "os" : "OS X", # also ok.
    }
}
browser = webdriver.Edge(**edge_options)
browser.get('https://kstory.hangame.com/en/index')

time.sleep(2)

select_server = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
    "span[class='js-selected-text']")

time.sleep(2)
select_server.click()


## below are still testing, not working yet 
select_server.send_keys('Conquest(US)')    
# dropdown = Select(select_server)
# dropdown.select_by_visible_text('Conquest(US)')
# dropdown.select_by_index('4')
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@data-type='server']/li[text()='Conquest(US)']").click()
```

Comment: getting `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

Comment: can you share the code you are trying with?

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time
edge_options = {
    "executable_path": "/Users/aatang/Desktop/edgedriver_mac64/msedgedriver",
    # ofcourse change path to driver you downloaded.
    "capabilities": {
        "platformName": 'mac os x',  # I get this from Chrome driver's capabilities
        # "os" : "OS X", # also ok.
    }
}
browser = webdriver.Edge(**edge_options)
browser.get('https://kstory.hangame.com/en/index')
browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//ul[@data-type='server']/li[text()='Conquest(US)']").click()

Comment: changed from `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@data-type='server']/li[text()='Conquest(US)']").click()` to `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@data-type='server']/li[text()='Conquest(US)']").click()`

Comment: You still have to keep the select_server.click() statement to make the dropdown visible and use the code i suggested to click on the desired option

Comment: That works. Thank you. I will work the other input and  submit part.

Comment: can you help on this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69230037/python-selenium-how-to-get-confirmation-after-submit