# Python Selenium - how to get confirmation after submit

Tags: python, selenium

I have a follow up question on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69215764/python-selenium-how-to-click-and-pick-from-the-dropdown-list-items-without-sel), I want to get any confirmation text after I hit submit button. Either the code works or not.

html - invalid example

```
<div class="serialModalArea js-serial-modal">
        <div class="serialModal">
            <div class="serialModal__notes">
                <img class="iconGlobal" src="/img/nav/nav_exclamation.svg"> <span>Invalid entry.</span>
            </div>
            <p class="serialModal__message js-modal-message"></p>
            <button type="button" class="serialModal__btn js-modal-btn">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

html - gift sent example

```
<div class="serialModalArea js-serial-modal success" style="display: block;">
        <div class="serialModal">
            <div class="serialModal__notes">
                <img class="iconGlobal" src="/img/nav/nav_exclamation.svg"> <span>Invalid entry.</span>
            </div>
            <p class="serialModal__message js-modal-message">Items have been sent. Please check your mailbox in game.</p>
            <button type="button" class="serialModal__btn js-modal-btn">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

And I tried:

```
get_confirmation_text = browser.find_element_by_class_name("serialModal__notes")
get_confirmation_text = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("p.serialModal__message")
```

Both return:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="1cfb4703be7e4c828a4c24d0ce1254a9", element="239dfa43-0408-4778-8f21-0ac93dad56c7")>
```

I would like to see `Invalid coupon code` in print statement.

My Code:

```
# coding: utf-8
from selenium import webdriver
import time

edge_options = {
    "executable_path": "/Users/aatang/Desktop/edgedriver_mac64/msedgedriver",
    # ofcourse change path to driver you downloaded.
    "capabilities": {
        "platformName": 'mac os x',  # I get this from Chrome driver's capabilities
        # "os" : "OS X", # also ok.
    }
}

browser = webdriver.Edge(**edge_options)
browser.get('https://kstory.hangame.com/en/index')

select_server = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
    "span[class='js-selected-text']")

select_server.click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//ul[@data-type='server']/li[text()='Conquest(US)']").click()

input_id = browser.find_element_by_name("monarch")
input_code = browser.find_element_by_name("serialcode")
input_id.send_keys("shushu1")
input_code.clear()
input_code.send_keys("191Sept")

submit = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/form/button')
submit.click()

message = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='serialModal']/p").text
print(message)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the username and coupon code you used?

Comment: Code expires after 1 day, or you can put any random characters.                       
Server: Worlord(SEA), ID: shushu1, code: 30chikisa

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
message = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='serialModal']/p").text
print(message)
```

Comment: it does not return anything. Added the my code block.